# Message count from Email-Inbox using Apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying  to get the number of Messages(count) from Email-INBOX using Apache camel Mail component.

```
from("imap://route-test-result@localhost?fetchsize=-1&delay=100")
```

But unfortunately I am unable to get number of Messages(count) from Inbox.

Does Apache camel provides any solution. Message count parameter is available in Apache Camel Header.

if so please provide me the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component, out of the box, does not give you that information as it split each mail message and process it individually. You may feed an additional destination with the result of your source like the following:

```
from("imap:yourConfig").log("${body}").bean(new MailCounter());
...
class MailCounter{

    int mailCounter = 0;

    public void count(String message){
        mailCounter++;
        System.out.println("You've received "+mailCounter+" so far...");
    }
}
```

Of course, you must work a little bit to reset the counter synch-ing with the mail consumer polling...